# Interface declaration - latest vs historical

Tags: design, object-oriented-design

Imagine there is an interface *IPriceProvider* which supposed to serve 2 needs: historical and latest. So I think we have 2 options here.

First:

```
PriceInfo GetLatestPrice(string symbol);
PriceInfo GetHistoricalPrice(string symbol, DateTime pointInTime);
```

Second:

```
PriceInfo GetPrice(string symbol, DateTime pointInTime);
```

In my opinion the second one is better, cause it's more flexible. Imagine, you have a Report which is as of now - so it calls this price provider like this:

```
GetPrice("EURUSD", _dateTime.Now);
```

So if there is a task to show what this exact report was showing yesterday at 17:35, I will just set _dateTime.Now to that point and my report will just work. But in case of the first approach, where I call it this way:

```
GetLatestPrice("EURUSD");
```

I will need to have a second implementation of IPriceProvider, then I will have wiring issue, I will need to configure my DI container in a special way and so on...

Am I missing something?
What are the Pros and Cons in these 2 approaches?

**Update:**

The Report class might look like this:

```
public class Report
{
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    private readonly IPriceProvider _priceProvider;

    public Report(IDateTime dateTime, IPriceProvider priceProvider)
    {
       _dateTime = dateTime;
       _priceProvider = priceProvider;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var latestPrice = _priceProvider.GetPrice("EURUSD", _dateTime.Now);
        // do the report calc here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would you need two implementations of `IPriceProvider` for the first option?

Comment: @BenAaronson please look at my Report class. If I used _priceProvider.GetLatest("EURUSD"). How would I run the whole thing for yesterday? Currently I have a second implementation of the PriceProvider which can be told that GetLatest currently is not latest, but latest at some point in time.

Comment: So what's the difference between getting the latest price at some point in the past and getting a historical time at the same point in the past?

Comment: What is an `IDateTime` ?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the conventions you're using, you come from the C# world.  Here's how to solve this with an [optional argument in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public PriceInfo GetPrice(string symbol, DateTime pointInTime = null)
```

The idea is if you call this with only the string:

```
GetPrice("EURUSD");
```

then `pointInTime` will be it's default value `_dateTime.Now`.  If you have to, use some flag value like `null` to signal that a method needs to be called to get the value now.  This way the above will be the same as:

```
GetPrice("EURUSD", _dateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I am not sure that you could use a non-constant default value of the optional parameter. Even if it was possible, I guess the optional parameter is pretty much the same as my number 1:  in the report class if you call it your way (GetPrice("EURUSD")), then how would you run it for any point in time?

Comment: @Max Use `null` as a flag, test for it and call `_dateTime.Now` from within `GetPrice`.  It's either that or figure out how to do some lambda magic with it.

Comment: Probably I didn't quite explained the situation. The main idea is that if I go my number 2, then I don't need to change anything PriceProvider implementation, Report implementation, DI - wiring, nothing. I will just set the Now time to yesterday and everything will work. 
What you are proposing is the same as my first option you call it not historically but latest. That means that you can't run it for yesterday.

Comment: @max that would look like this: GetPrice("EURUSD", _dateTime.yesterday); You don't need a second implementation. You just have one implementation that tests for null and sets it to now if it's null.  Because null is the default value you don't have to explicitly pass null.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you are actually mixing two different things here. One being the definition of an interface, the other an implementation detail of your report.

Regarding the design of the interface I would go for your first approach even though I would avoid the word *Historical*. Requirements can change and you might want to query a price which is not yet valid. Therefore I would define the interface like so:

```
PriceInfo GetCurrentPrice(string symbol);
PriceInfo GetPriceAt(string symbol, DateTime pointInTime);
```

In the report I would then use only `GetPriceAt` and pass `DateTime.Today` when no other date is specified. But as mentioned above this is an implementation detail.